# Why does using fsync() to flush writes to disk speed up access?

Tags: c, performance, fsync

We need an app to as much as possible, guarantee that when it reports a record persisted, it really was. I understand that to do this you use `fsync(fd)`. However, for some strange reason, it appears using fsync() speeds up the code that writes to disk, instead of slowing it down as one would expect.

Some sample test code returns the following results:

```
no sync() seconds:0.013388   writes per second:0.000001 
   sync() seconds:0.006268   writes per second:0.000002
```

Below is the code that produces these results:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void withSync() {
    int f = open( "/tmp/t8" , O_RDWR | O_CREAT );
    lseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET );
    int records = 10*1000;
    clock_t ustart = clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < records; i++) {
        write(f, "012345678901234567890123456789" , 30);
        fsync(f);
    }
    clock_t uend = clock();
    close (f);
    printf("   sync() seconds:%lf   writes per second:%lf\n", ((double)(uend-ustart))/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC), ((double)records)/((double)(uend-ustart))/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
}

void withoutSync() {
    int f = open( "/tmp/t10" , O_RDWR | O_CREAT );
    lseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET );
    int records = 10*1000;
    clock_t ustart = clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < records; i++) {
        write(f, "012345678901234567890123456789" , 30 );
    }
    clock_t uend = clock();
    close (f);
    printf("no sync() seconds:%lf   writes per second:%lf \n", ((double)(uend-ustart))/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC), ((double)records)/((double)(uend-ustart))/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    withoutSync();
    withSync();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The runtime is so small that the difference is most probably coming from variances in the execution environment. Try a test case that takes several seconds and run both versions through it.

Comment: File caching also play into this.  For example some UNIX systems run a daemon, flushd, which cleans up dirty cache pages.  Settings for what that does and how often it does that affect what you are dealing with. If you want guaranteed writes to you have to consider the environment

Comment: Both functions output zero time for me on Linux. When I increase the number of records to one million, then I get a measurable amount of time, but the no-sync version is a little faster.

Comment: Is `/tmp` mounted with `tmpfs`?

Comment: Since the "correct answers" are comments, Im adding the answer in the form of an answer as well. Thanks guys for your feedback!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is in the way you're attempting to time an I/O write.  You semantically want to measure the *wall-clock time* between I/O record writes, but you are using the C library function `clock`, which measures CPU execution time and not total time elapsed.  Use `clock_gettime` with a clock selection of `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` or, ideally, `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` (the latter being a Linux extension).

You are not collecting the total time elapsed between calls to `clock`: you are collecting an estimate of the amount of time your process was spinning CPU cycles.  Your disk I/O (specifically, both of the calls to `write` and `fsync`) is blocking, which means each of those system calls is handled by the kernel on your behalf and does not consume CPU within your process context. Hence, you need to measure the actual difference in *wall-clock time*, which as it sounds, is the total time elapsed in the real world, outside the scope of just your test program's process. Indeed, it is not CPU time you are concerned about at all with `fsync`. Most of the I/O operations' execution time will not be handled by the kernel or even the CPU; it will be due to the disk controller.

Additionally, small record sizes are OK as a benchmark.  It is a common use case for synchronized I/O (e.g., writing metadata for a transaction log).  To get the timing stability of larger record sizes, simply increase the number of loop iterations significantly per timer interval and average/amortize.  This will accurately model the cost of small blocking records being written and flushed synchronously.

Do consider `fdatasync` for improved performance.

Answer (score 0):

Much appreciate your comments, thanks! The comments suggesting increasing the test to a larger number of transactions are correct.  When using larger numbers of transactions `fsync()` does appear to do something. At least on OS/X 10.8:

1. When the write does not increase the file size, `fsync()` doubles the time it takes to complete the write.
2. When the write does increase the file size, `fsync()` is signficantly slower.